# Write panda to csv – append number if name already in use

Tags: python, csv

**Set-up**

I write pandas data-frames to CSV and place them in a single folder.

Each file has a name containing the date of creation, e.g.

```
'AA - 2017/02/20.csv'
```

---

**Problem**

When I create multiple dataframes on the same day, with a time difference in creation, the last created overwrites the previous created.

Instead, I'd like to have:

```
'AA - 2017/02/20.csv'
'AA - 2017/02/20.2.csv'
'AA - 2017/02/20.3.csv'
```

etcetera.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You can have a timestamp right? with HH:MM:SS at the end of the dates

Comment: Ah yes... Thanks. I'll do that in case no-one answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can differentiate the dates with a complete timestamp by using this

```
import time
import datetime
timestamp=str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H_%M_%S'))
```

You can append `timestamp` to your filename